# Is it possible to turn of syntax error highlighting in visual studio 2013/2015 for specific file extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reactjs

I'm currently working on some JSX files (React) but the wiggly lines are really distracting.

I have been looking for a way of disabling the syntax checker, without using something like resharper.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about `Tools > Options > Text Editor > JScript > Miscellaneous` and uncheck `Show syntax errors`?